Tikz "fill and pattern" a drawing
Is it possible to draw a shape and both fill it with colour and a pattern? E.g. \fill[white,draw=black,pattern=crosshatch dots] (5.45,0) rectangle (5.55,2)? Currently it draws the pattern but doesn't fill it.
I'm aware of the quesiton here but this is for a node not a drawing.
MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[cyan,draw=black] (0,0) -- (0,1) sin (1,1.25) cos (2,1) sin (3,0.75) cos (4,1) sin (5,1.25) cos (6,1) -- (6,0) -- (0,0);
        \fill[white,draw=black,pattern=crosshatch dots] (5.45,0) rectangle (5.55,2);
        \draw (0,1) -- (0,2) (6,1) -- (6,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Why does it matter that the duplicate uses a node? The technique and syntax of the preaction is identical.

You can use a preaction to fill the shape white before drawing the pattern:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[help lines,step=0.5,white] (-0.5,0) grid (6.5,2);
        \fill[cyan,draw=black] (0,0) -- (0,1) sin (1,1.25) cos (2,1) sin (3,0.75) cos (4,1) sin (5,1.25) cos (6,1) -- (6,0) -- (0,0);
        \fill[preaction={fill, white},draw,pattern=crosshatch dots] (5.45,0) rectangle (5.55,2);
        \draw (0,1) -- (0,2) (6,1) -- (6,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



Thanks that's perfect. Persumably then I can use \draw instead of \fill if my preaction is a fill? I.e. \draw[preaction={fill, white},pattern=crosshatch dots] (5.45,0) rectangle (5.55,2);

@jonnybolton16 It does not really matter too much, \draw, \fill etc. are just shortcuts for \path[...]
